Tikz baseline for multilines nodes
The anchor base is really nice to have… but when we use multiline text, I'd like to be able to refer to, e.g. base 1 for the base of the first line, base 2 for the base of the second line, base last for the base of the last line… Is it possible to have this in tikz? This would be practical to easily align nodes irrespective of the height/depth of its content. \strut can help sometimes by forcing the line to have a given depth, but it is not as flexible.

MWE
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mySpecialNode}{mm}{
  \node[draw,align=center](foo){#1};
  \node[draw,below=1.5mm of foo]{#2};
}

If I do not specify nodes positioning relative to baseline, adding a letter like ``p'' breakes the vertical alignement of the boxes

\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{2cm}\vspace{0pt}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \mySpecialNode{Abc}{def}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{2cm}\vspace{0pt}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \mySpecialNode{Abc}{Correct}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{2cm}\vspace{0pt}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \mySpecialNode{Abcp}{Incorrect}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%

If I use base instead, it works for single line content like:

\RenewDocumentCommand{\mySpecialNode}{mm}{
  \node[draw,align=center,text width=1cm](foo){\small #1};
  \node[draw, below=3mm of foo.base]{#2};
}
\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{2cm}\vspace{0pt}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \mySpecialNode{Abc}{def}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{2cm}\vspace{0pt}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \mySpecialNode{Abc}{Correct}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{2cm}\vspace{0pt}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \mySpecialNode{Abcp}{Correct!}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%

But fails on multiline content like:

\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{2cm}\vspace{0pt}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \mySpecialNode{Abc\\DEF}{def}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{2cm}\vspace{0pt}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \mySpecialNode{Abc\\GHI}{Correct}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{2cm}\vspace{0pt}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \mySpecialNode{Abc\\HTT}{Incorrect}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%

\newpage
Workaround is to use strut, but not as flexible (e.g. the node does not fit tightly without dirty workarounds like using another node to fit, we can't easily align the last baseline of two nodes that are next to each others with different inner sep with something as simple as \texttt{right=of mynode.last base, anchor=last base}):

\RenewDocumentCommand{\mySpecialNode}{mm}{
  \node[draw,align=center,text width=1cm](foo){\small #1\strut};
  \node[draw, below=3mm of foo]{#2};
}
\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{2cm}\vspace{0pt}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \mySpecialNode{Abc}{def}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{2cm}\vspace{0pt}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \mySpecialNode{Abc}{Correct}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{2cm}\vspace{0pt}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \mySpecialNode{Abcp}{Correct!}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%

\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{2cm}\vspace{0pt}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \mySpecialNode{Abc\\DEF}{def}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{2cm}\vspace{0pt}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \mySpecialNode{Abc\\GHI}{Correct}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t][3cm][t]{2cm}\vspace{0pt}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \mySpecialNode{Abc\\HTT}{Correct}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%


\end{document}


In the first example the text in the nodes are aligned, but since the "boxes" are centered, they are not aligned.  If you align the centers, then the text will not be aligned.  Now adding anchors involves creating a new shape (see section 106).  Note that specifying text width is eqivalent to using a \parbox, and specifying align is equivalent to using a one column tabular.  However, these only have one baseline.  You can select [tcb] which one to use, but only one at a time.

Specifying both text width and align at the same time is eqivalent to a \parbox uwith \RaggedRight (ragged2e package), \centering or  \RaggedLeft.  At least on the test sentence I used.

To do this, pgf would have to keep track of the baselines of different lines in the paragraph or of text in different rows of the table. I don't think pgf knows that information.
